# Wildfly 10: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory

Tags: java, wildfly-10

I've just wasted the last days for a strange random exception behaviour in wildfly 10...I've deployed my Java 7 EE .war to the wildfly, but suddenly I got this exception and deployment fail:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast
>   to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory

Answer (score 6):

The solution is: editing the standalone.xml of the wildfly, like adding some spaces and SAVE the file. Then just restart the wildfly and you can deploy your application again...so simple- hope i can help anyone out there.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution to a very frustrating bug

Answer (score 4):

In my case same problem was occurring.I am also using wildfly 10 and java 1.8 version. After reading the many solution i discovered this solution from  @goblingift comment and his pasted link.

**Solution:** 
In `pom.xml` i simply excluded the **dom4j** from my hibernate dependency.

```
<exclusion>
  <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

As i am using hibernate dependency like this in my `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
           <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
           <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#Dependency_Exclusions

Comment: This worked for me but my pom.xml was a little different.  I added the exclude to each of the dependencies in the pom.xml file that creates my projects .ear file.

Comment: Also, there was no reference to a dom4j jar in any of my pom.xml files but when I unzipped the ear file the dom4j.jar was there before I added the exclude.

Comment: Rather than excluding, you can try to scope the dom4j dependency as provided. I had to do this rather than excluding because somehow the dom4j dependency was required by other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is you're getting two different `org.dom4j.DocumentFactory` on your class path. The likely cause is you're including dom4j in your `WAR/lib` directory

Comment: Yes thats what i think first- but my project doesnt include a dom4j dependency...and after google the problem, i found several posts where the editing of standalone.xml fixed it.

Comment: I discovered that the adding of this dependency caused the issue: 
http://openimaj.org/openimaj-image/faces/dependencies.html

There is the dom4j included...What can i do to fix the deployment error?

Comment: If you're using maven you can add an exclude when you define the dependency. See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#Dependency_Exclusions